# NSString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString doesn't work correctly with escape charecters

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I want to remove `"` from `NSString` but it just doesn't work out.

The string comes from XMLParser:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser
 didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
 qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
  if([elementName isEqualToString:@"li"]){
      _isAnswer = NO;
  }else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"span"]){
     NSString *immutableString = [NSString stringWithString:currentElementValue];//currentElementValue is myMutableString
     NSString* myString = [immutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"00000"];
     myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"״" withString:@"00000"];
     myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"“" withString:@"00000"];
     myString = [myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"”" withString:@"00000"];
```

NSLog (@"myString - ", myString);
      }
    }

- The string from the xml has a `"`
- The log:

  ```
  myString - this is the " string
  ```

  instead of:

  ```
  myString - this is the 00000 string
  ```

Comment: Define "doesn't work out".

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work - you simply log out the original string again, not the modified one. (BTW, is that real code? How does `NSLog()` know it has to print another string besides the format string if you don't provide it with the `%@` conversion specifier? `NSLog (@"newString - ", newString);` should be `NSLog (@"newString - %@", newString);`...)

Comment: You are replacing `myString` but logging newString.

Comment: @Luda - based on your update, please also log `myString` before you call `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString`. You were logging `newString` in both places. Log `myString` both before and after since that is what you are changing.

Comment: Now you are doing the same mistake again: repeatedly replacing characters in `immutableString` but assigning to `myString`. In the last three lines, replace `immutableString` by `myString`.

Comment: Hi @NikolaiRuhe, It was a mistype. The code is correct. The question had been edited

Comment: Thank you my dear people! Thank you for all your patience! It finally worked. Thank you thank you thank you!!!

Comment: It's absolutely unclear to me why a chaotic question like this gets any upvotes. To me it seems that neither the question nor any answer helps anybody except maybe the OP. The continuous edits and repeated mistakes make it worthless for anybody else. Plus, it took quite some time and patience of anybody who tried to help. The general low quality of the question and how it is asked really don't convince me it is worth five upvotes.

Comment: It helped the OP for sure. It did took some effort from those who helped, and I deeply thankful for that. The five upvotes should't convince you of anything. They are just there. Peace man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I've tested your code, everything is OK here**. There is a problem somewhere in your code, which you didn't shared...

```
    NSString *str = @"LOL \"... ";

    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"00000"];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

Here is the output:

```
>>  LOL "... 
>>  LOL 00000...
```

*Show us how your string is initialized maybe*

---

EDIT:

1) First make sure that it it `"` character, not ״, “ or    ”

2) Try something like this, **it has the same result as my first answer.**

```
    NSString *str = @"LOL \"... ";

    unichar const maskChar = 0x0022; // Code of " char
    NSString *mask = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:&maskChar length:1];

    NSLog(@"%@",str);
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:mask withString:@"00000"];
    NSLog(@"%@",str);
```

If second solution doesn't work than it is not `"` character